# Results from two tables

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, cursor, android-sqlite

I have an Android application with SQLite database, where I display search results for user input.
I have 2 tables, both have the same columns, but one is used for user's custom data.
When user searches for something, I would like to display UNIQUE results from both tables together.
How would I do that? Is it possible to use `JOIN`? Or should I query each table separately and then join the `Cursors`?

Tables:

```
_id  a    b  c
---------------
1  data data 3
2  data data 10
3 data data 1
```

and

```
_id  a    b  c
---------------
1  data data 10
2  data data 6
3 data data 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a Union into the two tables

```
SELECT a,b,c
FROM table1
[WHERE condition]

UNION

SELECT a,b,c
FROM table2
[WHERE condition]
```